# getting Xpath for searched elements

Tags: python, xpath

I can get list of products from web page using this code

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://monument.pl/pol_m_DESKOROLKA_Deski-162.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
VENDORLISTn = tree.xpath('//a[@class="firm_name"]/text()')
print VENDORLISTn
```

I get the following result

```
['Almost', 'Almost', 'Almost', 'Enjoi', 'Real', 'Boulevard', 'Almost', 'Almost', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Cliche', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Blind', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Enjoi', 'Antihero']
```

How can I get the list of paths to these elements? It may look like this:

```
['//*[@id="search"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/div[3]/div/a','//*[@id="search"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div/a',etc....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VENDORLISTn` is just a `list` of **strings**. I guess there is no way to generate `XPath` for that, but you can get absolute `XPath` for each link as below:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://monument.pl/pol_m_DESKOROLKA_Deski-162.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
VENDORLISTn = tree.xpath('//a[@class="firm_name"]')
for link in VENDORLISTn:
    etree.ElementTree(tree).getpath(link)
```

Output:

```
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/table/tr[1]/td[1]/div/div[3]
/div/a'
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]
/div/a'
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/table/tr[1]/td[3]/div/div[3]
/div/a'
....
```